# Is anyone actively researching distributed prediction models?

Tags: reference-request, dc.distributed-comp

Is there any current, ongoing, research being performed, looking specifically at implementing prediction models on a distributed system? I'm specifically interested in work where the underlying system can be modeled as a network of devices that has significant churn in terms of connections between the nodes, and nodes joining/leaving the network (for example, a peer-to-peer network).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no information about any particular prediction model in your request, therefore, I think you should look through the paper ["PLDA: Parallel Latent Dirichlet Allocation for Large-scale Applications"](http://www.springerlink.com/content/643q4813227844n3/) (2009) of Google researchers. See also their [project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/plda/).

Besides, [Google Prediction API](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/) project might be valuable resource related to the topic, too.